# Compile Asterisk with relative path

Tags: asterisk

I work with Asterisk 11.2.1 and I want  to compile it with  --prefix

```
  mindia@localhost asterisk-11.2.1]$ ./configure --prefix=../
```

This command throws exception

```
  configure: error: expected an absolute directory name for --prefix: ..
```

I want to use relative path.Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you explain why you need the prefix to be a relative path? It supposed to be something like /usr or /home/username

Answer (score 2):

you can write it as below

```
mindia@localhost asterisk-11.2.1]$ ./configure --prefix=/relative/path
```

not

```
--prefix=../something
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the clear response from `configure`

```
configure: error: expected an absolute directory name for --prefix: ..
```

So you are not allowed to use relative path, and you need to provide absolute path. The reason of this behavior, I think, is in the fact that relative path has no sense due to the `prefix` directory path. If you still have to use relative path, then just use some of the `bash` or your operation system utilities to convert the relative path to absolute path and substitute that path to your configure command.